# PS 4.0 Windows 7 / Windows 2012 R2 Same script different result

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

Object (`$var`) created using `[pscustomObject]@{...}`. On my development PC (Win7 x64, PS 4.0) all is fine, a custom object:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> $var | gm


   TypeName: Deserialized.System.Management.Automation.**PSCustomObject**

Name               MemberType   Definition                                                                                                 
----               ----------   ----------                                                                                                 
Equals             Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj)                                                                             
GetHashCode        Method       int GetHashCode()                                                                                          
GetType            Method       type GetType()                                                                                             
ToString           Method       string ToString()                                                                                          
AddinExists        NoteProperty  AddinExists=null                                                                                          
AddinName          NoteProperty Deserialized.System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject AddinName=                                        
ComputerName       NoteProperty System.String ComputerName=xxxxxx                                                                  
Description        NoteProperty  Description=null                                                                                          
FriendlyName       NoteProperty  FriendlyName=null                                                                                         
PSComputerName     NoteProperty System.String PSComputerName=xxxxxx                                                                
PSPath             NoteProperty  PSPath=null                                                                                               
PSShowComputerName NoteProperty System.Boolean PSShowComputerName=True                                                                     
RunspaceId         NoteProperty System.Guid RunspaceId=xxxx4-015f-xxxx-a5a0-6a1861d0f164                                                
SearchScope        NoteProperty System.String SearchScope=HKU:\S-1-5-21-13434734552-3593029396-1545345-1234513\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\...
UserLoggedOn       NoteProperty System.Boolean UserLoggedOn=True                                                                           
UserName           NoteProperty System.String UserName=John
```

But on the 2012 R2 server (PS 4.0) it "sees" it as a hastable:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> $var | gm


   TypeName: Deserialized.System.Collections.**Hashtable**

Name               MemberType            Definition                                                                                                                                          
----               ----------            ----------                                                                                                                                          
Add                Method                void Add(System.Object key, System.Object value), void IDictionary.Add(System.Object key, System.Object value)                                      
Clear              Method                void Clear(), void IDictionary.Clear()                                                                                                               
Clone              Method                System.Object Clone(), System.Object ICloneable.Clone()                                                                                             
Contains           Method                bool Contains(System.Object key), bool IDictionary.Contains(System.Object key)                                                                      
ContainsKey        Method                bool ContainsKey(System.Object key)                                                                                                                  
ContainsValue      Method                bool ContainsValue(System.Object value)                                                                                                              
CopyTo             Method                void CopyTo(array array, int arrayIndex), void ICollection.CopyTo(array array, int index)                                                           
Equals             Method                bool Equals(System.Object obj)                                                                                                                      
GetEnumerator      Method                System.Collections.IDictionaryEnumerator GetEnumerator(), System.Collections.IDictionaryEnumerator IDictionary.GetEnumerator(), System.Collections...
GetHashCode        Method                int GetHashCode()                                                                                                                                    
GetObjectData      Method                void GetObjectData(System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo info, System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext context), void ISerializable...
GetType            Method                type GetType()                                                                                                                                      
OnDeserialization  Method                void OnDeserialization(System.Object sender), void IDeserializationCallback.OnDeserialization(System.Object sender)                                 
Remove             Method                void Remove(System.Object key), void IDictionary.Remove(System.Object key)                                                                           
ToString           Method                string ToString()                                                                                                                                   
PSComputerName     NoteProperty          System.String PSComputerName=LDNXD6002520                                                                                                           
PSShowComputerName NoteProperty          System.Boolean PSShowComputerName=True                                                                                                              
RunspaceId         NoteProperty          System.Guid RunspaceId=basaaf35e-cdbb-4b5c-97bc-c9asdcaf8                                                                                          
Item               ParameterizedProperty System.Object Item(System.Object key) {get;set;}                                                                                                    
Count              Property              int Count {get;}                                                                                                                                    
IsFixedSize        Property              bool IsFixedSize {get;}                                                                                                                              
IsReadOnly         Property              bool IsReadOnly {get;}                                                                                                                               
IsSynchronized     Property              bool IsSynchronized {get;}                                                                                                                          
Keys               Property              System.Collections.ICollection Keys {get;}                                                                                                          
SyncRoot           Property              System.Object SyncRoot {get;}                                                                                                                        
Values             Property              System.Collections.ICollection Values {get;}
```

Does anyone have any ideas what is causing the anomaly and how I might be able to rectify it? It's driving me nuts and screwing up my `Export-Csv`.

Here is how `$var` is defined:

```
$var = [PSCustomObject]@{
                    ComputerName = $ComputerName
                    UserName = $UserName
                    AddinName = $(if($v1){Split-Path $v1.PSPath -leaf})
                    FriendlyName = $v1.FriendlyName
                    Description = $v1.Description
                    PSPath = $v1.PSPath
                    UserLoggedOn = $False
                    PathExists = $v2
                    SearchScope = $searchScopes[$i]
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know why, but the $blah=[PSCustomObject]@{...} method just would not work. I had to resort to the PS 2.0 method.

I changed:

```
$i = -1
            $searchScopes | ForEach-Object{
                $i++
                #Write-host $_ -ForegroundColor Green
                try
                {
                    Get-ChildItem -Path $_ -ErrorAction stop| ForEach-Object{
                        try
                        {
                            $v1 = Get-ItemProperty -Path $_.PSPath -ErrorAction Stop
                            $v2 = $True #$searchScopes[$i]
                        }
                        catch
                        {
                            $v2 = $False #"Addin / product not found"
                        }
                    }
                }       
                catch
                {
                    Write-Verbose "$($error[0].Exception.Message) User: $Username, Computer: $ComputerName"
                }       

                $oRes2 = [PSCustomObject]@{
                    ComputerName = $ComputerName
                    UserName = $UserName
                    AddinName = $(if($v1){Split-Path $v1.PSPath -leaf})
                    FriendlyName = $v1.FriendlyName
                    Description = $v1.Description
                    PSPath = $v1.PSPath
                    UserLoggedOn = $True
                    AddinExists = $v2
                    SearchScope = $searchScopes[$i]

                }
             $oRes2
             }

        } #End ScriptBlock


        $SearchResults = Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $scriptblock -ArgumentList $ObjectSid, $ComputerName, $UserName -ComputerName $ComputerName #-ErrorAction Stop
        Write-Host "================="

    $SearchResults
```

To this:

```
$oRes5 = @()
            $i = -1
            $searchScopes | ForEach-Object{
                $v2 = $null
                $i++
                #Write-host $_ -ForegroundColor Green
                try
                {
                    Get-ChildItem -Path $_ -ErrorAction stop| ForEach-Object{
                        try
                        {
                            $v1 = Get-ItemProperty -Path $_.PSPath -ErrorAction Stop
                            $v2 = $True #$searchScopes[$i]
                        }
                        catch
                        {
                            $v2 = $False #"Addin / product not found"
                        }
                    }
                }       
                catch
                {
                    Write-Verbose "$($error[0].Exception.Message) User: $Username, Computer: $ComputerName"
                }       

                $oRes4 = @{
                    ComputerName = $ComputerName
                    UserName = $UserName
                    #AddinName = $(if($v1){Split-Path $v1.PSPath -leaf})
                    FriendlyName = $v1.FriendlyName
                    Description = $v1.Description
                    PSPath = $v1.PSPath
                    UserLoggedOn = $True
                    AddinExists = $v2
                    SearchScope = $searchScopes[$i]
                }
             #$oRes4
             $oRes5 += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $oRes4
             } #End foreach
             $oRes5
        } #End ScriptBlock


        $SearchResults = Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $scriptblock -ArgumentList $ObjectSid, $ComputerName, $UserName -ComputerName $ComputerName #-ErrorAction Stop
        Write-Host "================="

    return $SearchResults
```

A bit messy, but I couldn't spend any more time on it.